# rank error in php displaying one rank only

Tags: php, rank

```
$avr = intval($result->markk / 11); 
$numbers = array($avr);
rsort($numbers);

$arr = $arr1 = array();
$i = $rank = 1;

foreach ($numbers as $key => $value) {

    $arr[$value][] = $value;
}

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        echo $value1 . "- rank " . $rank . "<br>";
        $rank++; // Increment the rank
    }
    $i++;
}
```

the above code is showing one rank only how i can fix that

```
rank 1
rank 2
rank 2
rank 4
```

Comment: `$numbers` is an array with just one element. What's the point of sorting it or looping over it?

Comment: Edit what? You only have one value `$avr`. What are you expecting to rank?

Comment: if  i remove array the whole code doesn't work so can you tell me a way i can rank students without using array

Comment: It doesn't make sense -- you need multiple values if you want to rank them.

Comment: `$numbers` should be an array with the scores of all the students, not just one score.

Comment: the values are in the database and i want to rank them

Comment: Yeah, but you're only putting one of them in `$numbers`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put all the students' averages in `$numbers`, not just one average.

To get the same rank for tied scores, you should increment `$rank` in the outer loop, not the inner loop. Increment it by the number of tied scores.

There's no need for `$arr1` or `$i`. And your loops never use the keys, so you don't need `$key =>` in `foreach.

```
$numbers = [];
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $numbers[] = round($result->markk / 11);
}

$arr = [];
foreach ($numbers as $value) {
    $arr[$value][] = $value;
}

$rank = 1;
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $value1) {
        echo $value1 . "- rank " . $rank . "<br>";
    }
    $rank += count($value);
}
```